# radio button not selected on jquery dialog box in ajax calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, jquery-ui, jquery-dialog

I have a problem here. I have a jquery modal dialog on which I have 2 radio buttons. In my code I have jQuery ajaxStart and ajaxStop handlers to check for Ajax requests (I also have an other jquery dialog pop up to display a Loading... message or something when there is an Ajax request executing). When I select each radio button, an ajax request is made. The problem I am having is that because of the ajax events (ajaxStart, ajaxStop), when I click on the radio buttons, they are not selected (although I get the correct value of my radio button). Any idea what might cause this?

You can see an illustration of what I meean with this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jTGCF/65/)

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

It seems the problem comes from the `modal: true` option of the `#ajax-dialog` dialog. If you set the option to false, it works as expected. Upgrading to the latest version of jquery and jquery ui did not seem to resolve the problem.

---

**Solution 1**

Set the modal option to `false`.

```
$('#ajax-dialog').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    modal: false, // set to false
    title: 'Loading...'
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/2k5WW/)**

---

**Solution 2**

You can use the plugin [BlockUI](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#overview) which allows *blocking* the full page or an specific element. it works by showing a overlay div (over the page or the element) forbidding any interaction with the underlying content. You can display a message and customize the look&feel.

Blocking a dialog content (with the radio boxes):

```
$("#ajax-dialog").ajaxStart(function() {
    $('#gender-dialog').block({ 
            message: '<h1>Loading...</h1>', 
            css: { border: '3px solid #a00' } 
        }); 
});

$("#ajax-dialog").ajaxStop(function() {
    $('#gender-dialog').unblock(); 
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/U92uu/)**

Blocking the full page:

```
$("#ajax-dialog").ajaxStart(function() {
    $.blockUI({ message: '<h1>Loading...</h1>', baseZ: 2000 });  
});

$("#ajax-dialog").ajaxStop(function() {
    $.unblockUI();
});
```

Note the option `baseZ` in this case, this is the z-index of the overlay, which has a default value of 1000. Set it to something higher than the dialog to cover it.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/didierg/FBNUw/)**